# How to overcome issue of ".. is not a function" while referring to earlier defined function expression in same js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

On accessing function expression in the same file, gives an error of .. "is not a function". 
I need this below function expression to be available both outside the js file to other .js files and as well inside the same js file.

I have tried below things from below blogs, nothing seems to work
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2923

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function

```
// this is in abc.js
function qpValidations() {
     this.addDaystoGetDate = function(noOfDays){
     ... 
     }

      this.constructDate = function(){
        this.addDaystoGetDate(2);// here issue is coming, where trying to                                        
                                  //call function in same .js file
      }

}
module.exports = new qpValidations();
```

Any help is most appreciated!!, though this issue occurred many times with me, tried avoiding file circular dependency and as well clubbing function expression and declaration, had solved the issues earlier, but now again it has poped up not sure what the root cause of this issue..?

Comment: It's a bit unclear where you're having an issue. So you're saying when you require it in another file, the function works, but when you use the function in the same file, it doesn't? How do you call the function from within the same file?

Comment: Yes,  this.constructDate = function(){
        this.addDaystoGetDate(2);// here issue is coming, where trying to                                        
                                  //call function in same .js file
      }

Comment: I hope issue is clear now, let me know if it isnt

Comment: As per this post, i am verifying that addDaystoGetDate() is been hoisted earlier. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

Comment: You still haven't posted the code you're using that's actually breaking.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only having issues calling the function in the same file, it's hard to help because you haven't shown HOW you're trying to call it. But I would suggest you try something like this:

```
// this is in abc.js
function qpValidations() {
     this.addDaystoGetDate = function(noOfDays){
     ... 
     }

      this.constructDate = function(){
        this.addDaystoGetDate (2);// here issue is coming
      }

}

const newQp = new qpValidations()
module.exports = newQp;

newQp.addDaystoGetDate();
```

Comment: Hi TKoL! Thank you for your super fast response! I tried as tagged in this comment line, // here issue is coming

Comment: Thats where i am trying to call addDaystoGetDate () function in constructDate function

Comment: Your example code doesn't call the constructDate function anywhere. It's hard to help you without examples

Comment: The same when i tried changing now as function declaration it works smoothly (same lines call of function changed as addDaystoGetDate (2) thts it)                                                                                               But this way cannot access this function outside in other js files :(

Comment: Well I did what you did, in another file required abc.js and called `qpFns.constructDate()`, and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

addDaystoGetDate function required a parameter. try sending a parameter when you call the function.

```
newQp.addDaystoGetDate(5);
newQp.addDaystoGetDate("some text"); //or whatever you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer, it was from one of my buddy:), the scope of this.addDaystoGetDate()
gets changed when it is called inside another this.constructDate() function. So as a solution assign "this" object to some variable like below, further can be referred same wherever we come across this

```
function validation(){
    var refObj = this;

    refObj.addDaystoGetDate =function(dayscount){
    }

    refObj.constructDate = function(){
     refObj.addDaystoGetDate(2);
    }


} 
module.exports = new validtaion();
```